# How to texture large floors?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, workflow

I am making a game using Blender, Substance, and UE4. I have been encountering issues applying materials to my floors and ceilings. I want to know the most efficient way to texture floors and/or larger objects. [image: My floor in UE4 with materials applied from Substance]

I usually have luck splitting these pieces up, but in turn that costs the engine. [image: This is what my asset/floor looks like in Blender]

Comment: What kind of issue are you talking about? Do you want to use image textures or procedural textures? In the first case you need to use repeatable images

Comment: I am using procedural textures/materials from substance. @moonboots

Answer (score 3):

Use UV coordinates, and UV map projected from an orthogonal view, with a square rendering aspect:

[image]

I created a camera, pointing down at the floor, to keep track of where I'm mapping from.  By adopting the position of this camera and doing a project-from-view unwrap, I can keep the scale of all UVs consistent very easily.  So long as I'm using tiling textures, I won't have any seams or stretching on any geometry that lies in the camera plane.

Note the rendering dimensions.  Using equal values for X and Y resolution is what keeps my view aspect square for the unwrap.

Any time I create a new floor object, I can adopt the position of my camera and project from that view, and be guaranteed that the UV of that new object is consistent with the UV of my other floors.

If I want this to be dynamic, to keep up with changes I make to the geometry, I can use a UV Project modifier (and whenever I'm finished with the geometry and ready for export, apply that modifier.)  If you do that, be sure to set the camera to orthogonal mode.

An alternative is to use geometry/position as my texture input and then bake to different UV when I'm ready for export.  That will work as well.  The problem with that is that you will probably want to reuse UV space on your floors, rather than bake all of your floor textures into the 0,1 UV space.